# close display in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, display

I want to execute a code quickly which is using some well established toolbox available on internet. This toolbox has some display command in it and I am guessing, if I can disable this display command then I might execute this code quickly (I do not want to alter the toolbox, in case you are wondering). Is there any code which can manually on/off the display at command window? Thnaks.

Comment: Is the "display" you want to close shown in the command window of Matlab or as a figure that is opened by the toolbox functions?

Comment: I have got the answer in the duplicate question. Thanks.